# Get onActivityResult not on the same class send startActivityForResult

Tags: android, fragment, runnable, start-activity

I try to make the speech recognize as show in this link https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/developing-android-applications-with-voice-recognition-features.

It uses a run() method to make it thread on the background, which I call it from the fragment like this `SpeechRecognitionHelper.run(getActivity());`
Then in show it use

```
ownerActivity.startActivityForResult(intent,SystemData.VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
```

where the ownerActivity is the getActivity() I pass it on the run().
So I was thinking I can implement the `onActivityResult(..)` in the Fragment(which call the run() and get the result on the fly.
But it is showing me a mistake when trying so.

1. Can't I get the result in the Fragment if I specify it even I use it in anther class?
2. If not how can I get the result if I use the run() method? How get the result if I have to use also the `startActivityForResult`?

Answer (score 0):

`onActivityResult()` is the only way you can get the speech recognition results from the recognizer activity.

If you invoke it from `Activity.startActivityForResult()`, you have to override `Activity.onActivityResult()` on that same Activity subclass to get the result.

If you invoke it from `Fragment.startActivityForResult()`, you have to override `Fragment.onActivityResult()` on that same Fragment subclass to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

`Can't I get the result in the Fragment if I specify it even I use it in anther class?`

From the link you shared `startRecognitionActivity` method expected the `Activity` and uses the `Activity` context to start the `Voice Recognition Activity` , so the result will be passed to the activity. Modify the method to start the `Activity` from `Fragment` context.

```
    private static void startRecognitionActivity(Fragment callerFragment) {
   // create an Intent with “RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH” action

   // start Activity and wait for result on fragment
    callerFragment.startActivityForResult(intent, SystemData.VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
```

}

Now override the `onActivityResult` on `Fragment` class

```
// Fragment Results handler
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// handle the result
if (requestCode == SystemData.VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
     // Do your stuff here
  }
}
```

Comment: So you mean to write all the public class SpeechRecognitionHelper as an inner class in my Fragment? Because how they write it it is look that it is use a class of its own where the private static void startRecognitionActivity is part of it?